# A moderator accidentally created a chat event, then deleted it, but it still shows in the upcoming events list. How can they remove it?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools, chat-event

For context:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57011728#57011728

A moderator in a chatroom created a joke event, then deleted the event once they realized it sent out a site-wide announcement, including an "upcoming event" notification in the sidebar. However, apparently the event being deleted didn't remove it from the sidebar.

Now, this event starts in a couple of hours, so it's not a big issue that it's on the list. But just for future reference: if a chat event is created in error, what is the correct procedure to remove it in such a way that it's no longer shown in "upcoming events" in the sidebar?

Comment: Should I blame caching? Most likely

Comment: I think a dev needs to remove the entry from the bulletin.

Comment: Removal from the buletin is a seperate process indeed @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog, as per dupe.

Comment: Nope, a mod on the room's parent site can remove it from the bulletin which I have done :)